# Tokenize a stream in C++ using regex

Tags: c++, regex, tokenize

I would like to tokenize a stream in C++ using a regular expression similar to the way this is done for a string:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& source, const std::regex& re)
{
    auto tokens = std::vector<std::string>(
        std::sregex_token_iterator{ begin(source), end(source), re, -1 },
        std::sregex_token_iterator{}
    );
    return tokens;
}
```

The difference would be passing an `istream` as the `source` variable.

I could first copy the contents of the stream into a string, and then perform the tokenization, but this seems to be inefficient.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @NutCracker - Well, I have a stream that contains data and I'd like to get it out as a series of values (tokens) without copying the whole stream to a string first.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code where you use `std::istream`?

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent Are you reading a file? If so, are trying to tokenise each line?

Comment: In this case, I have a file ```istream```, though the data could be from a ```stringstream```. The stream contains a series of text fragments.  They may be separated by one of several different grammatical marks (e.g., a comma, period, parentheses, or square brackets), thus the need for regex.  I'd like to break these fragments out into a vector of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform_reduce(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),
               vector<string>{},
               [](auto&& a, auto&& b) {
                 auto acc = [](auto&& h, auto&& w) { h.emplace_back(w); return move(h); };
                 if constexpr (is_same_v<decay_t<decltype(a)>, vector<string>>)
                   return accumulate(istream_iterator<string>(b), istream_iterator<string>(), move(a), acc);
                 else
                   return accumulate(istream_iterator<string>(a), istream_iterator<string>(), move(b), acc);
               },
               [&](auto l) { replace_if(l.begin(), l.end(), is_word_seperators, ' '); return stringstream{move(l)}; }
             );
```